# Chrome suddenly switch to "Night mode"

Tags: google-chrome

Somehow I got this -> ["night mode"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfxYY.png) in my Chrome. My PC was suddenly reset(Windows 10) and when it's back I got "night mode" only in Chrome.

First I turn off all extensions and [flux](https://justgetflux.com/). The change did not happen. Then I remove flux and Chrome. With CCleaner I clean remains. Install Chrome again but problem is still there.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is it just Chrome, or entire Windows?

Comment: Could you please check whether you have enabled the Night light from Display settings?

Comment: Strange thing is that problem is only in Chrome http://prntscr.com/kd97zc .
"Night light" is turned off in Display settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this problem. In Chrome Settings, turn off "hardware acceleration" https://prnt.sc/kdp7o2 and reset Chrom browser.